# Removing and Appending in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've been at this problem for a while now, and I can't seem to figure it out. I have a checkbox that when checked, deletes a div containing a textbox. When that checkbox is unchecked the aforementioned textbox should return to the page. The removal works, but the append doesn't.

This is what I'm currently working with code wise:

```
$('#ResultsNoData1').click(function () {
    var parent = document.getElementById('Results1').parentNode;
    var child = document.getElementById('Results1');

    if (this.checked) {
        parent.removeChild(child);
    }
    else {
        parent.appendChild(child);
    }
});
```

My original design worked by doing the following:

```
$('#ResultsNoData1').click(function () {
    (this.checked) ? $('.results1').hide() : $('.results1').show();
});
```

However the functionality I need to recreate is actually removing the data from this textbox from being accessed on the site while hiding the textbox itself at the same time. This doesn't provide that functionality.

[Current example](http://jsfiddle.net/cx96g/1/)

Comment: If you remove it, it is gone. You cannot add it again. You'll have to add a new textbox, or don't remove it at all but hide it instead.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using plain Javascript for some bits and jQuery for others?

Comment: I'm mixing javascript and jQuery because I'm a bad programmer in all honesty. I thought using both would somehow be beneficial to my learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/cx96g/5/

Your issue is that you were trying to set parent inside your click, but once child is removed it would fail.

```
var parent = document.getElementById('Results1').parentNode;
var child = document.getElementById('Results1');
$('#ResultsNoData1').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        node = parent.removeChild(child);
    }
    else {
        parent.appendChild(child);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not set `child` first and then get `parent` relative to it? Cmon people!

Comment: @Mathletics Because I didn't want to totally restructure his code. One step at a time.

Comment: Yours didn't work because once you've removed the child in the click function. Then the next time the click event is called it can't set the `parent` variable because `child` no longer exists in the `DOM`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to show and hide that TextBox not remove.

```
$('#ResultsNoData1').click(function () {    
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#Results1").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#Results1").show();
    }
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cx96g/4/)

Comment: Or `$("#Results1").toggle(!this.checked)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ResultsNoData1').click(function () {
    (this.checked) ? $('#Results1').val('').parent().hide() : $('#Results1').parent().show();
    (this.checked) ? $('.results1casual').hide() : $('.results1casual').show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WcvP/2/)

Comment: Like @HarshitTailor's answer, only put some serious effort into making it less readable and (theoretically) less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right way but missing one small thing need to remove value from the textbox.

```
$('#ResultsNoData1').click(function () {
    (this.checked) ? $('.results1').hide() : $('.results1').show().val("");
});
```

or

```
$('#ResultsNoData1').click(function () {
    (this.checked) ? $('.results1').hide().val("") : $('.results1').show();
});
```

And this is the right way(show/hide) the textarea.